# How to translate a Ruby regex to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ruby, regex

In Ruby I have a regex to get a string formatted like "@xxx":

```
(/(?<!\S)@[A-Za-z0-9\-]+/)
```

I also need this regex on the client side, but JavaScript can't read this.

How can I change this regex to JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you don't have lookbehind in JavaScript regular expression so you can't use `(?<!\S)` in a JavaScript regex.

You can use:

```
/(?:^|\s)(@[A-Za-z0-9-]+)/
```

And use captured group #1 for your matched text.

**Alternatively** you can use [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/) library in JS and use the lookbehind feature.

Comment: sorry i don't know about it. now I have ticked it. thanks again